# Importing multiple text files to new excel work books with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script I put together to import multiple text files that are semi colon delimited in to new workbooks for each file that is selected. It is about 99% functional aside from the fact it seems to paste all of the data from the selected text files in a column after the correctly imported columns in the new workbook. I'm not entirely sure what part of the code is causing this to be pasted in to that particular row. Below is the main part of the code. Can anyone identify where the issue might be?

Also I just want to say thanks to the community here. I have learned a lot by going through other posts on this forum.

```
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
  (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")



For i = LBound(FilesToOpen) To UBound(FilesToOpen)
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(FilesToOpen(i))
    Set wks = wkb.ActiveSheet
     With wks.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & FilesToOpen(i), Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Where do you want the output to go?  Right now you are creating a `QueryTable` in `wks` which is the `ActiveSheet` of `wkb` which is the file you just opened.  Do you want the output in the file that you are opening?  Next, if that is what you want, then `Destination:=Range("A1")` is determining the actual spot on that `Worksheet` where is starts the new table.

Comment: I am attempting to put the output in the new file I am opening. For each text file I open a new workbook is created and the data is posted to that new workbook. It is posting the data to the new workbook however it takes the original data from the text file and posts it in the first row right after the correctly imported data and I am a bit stumped as to why it is doing that. I could simply manually delete the row but I want to determine why it's happening to clean up the process.

Comment: Your code is opening the text file _as a `Workbook`_ which is the same as going to `File->Open`.  The original data is there because **it was there when you started**.  If you truly want a **new** `Workbook` you need to explicitly create it with `Set wkb = Workbooks.Add` instead of your current line.  There is no need to `Open` the text file if you want to create a data connection to it; `Connection` handles all that.

Comment: Thanks Byron. I was stepping through my code and found that line was the issue. With that and your suggestion it looks like I am good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the use of `Workbooks.Open` to get a new `Workbook`.  You are really opening the text file in the same way as going to `File->Open`.  If you want a *new* `Workbook` to dump the data, create it explicitly using `Set wkb = Workbooks.Add()` instead of your current call to `Workbooks.Open`.  You are seeing the file's data because you opened the file first.

**Full code**

```
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
  (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")



For i = LBound(FilesToOpen) To UBound(FilesToOpen)
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Add()
    Set wks = wkb.ActiveSheet
     With wks.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & FilesToOpen(i), Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next i
```